# Why am I getting Nan after adding relu activation in LSTM?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, relu

I have simple LSTM network that looks roughly like this:

```
lstm_activation = tf.nn.relu

cells_fw = [LSTMCell(num_units=100, activation=lstm_activation), 
            LSTMCell(num_units=10, activation=lstm_activation)]

stacked_cells_fw = MultiRNNCell(cells_fw)

_, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=stacked_cells_fw,
                              inputs=embedding_layer,
                              sequence_length=features['length'],
                              dtype=tf.float32)

output_states = [s.h for s in states]
states = tf.concat(output_states, 1)
```

My question is. When I don't use activation (activation=None) or use tanh everything works but when I switch relu I'm keep getting "NaN loss during training", why is that?. It's 100% reproducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `relu activation function` inside the `lstm cell`, it is guaranteed that all the outputs from the cell, as well as the cell state, will be strictly `>= 0`. Because of that, your gradients become extremely large and are exploding. For example, run the following code snippet and observe that the outputs are never `< 0`.

```
X = np.random.rand(4,3,2)
lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(5, activation=tf.nn.relu)
hidden_states, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=lstm_cell, inputs=X, dtype=tf.float64)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print(sess.run(hidden_states))
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation! So it works without any activation because cell can have values <0 and this balances the gradient?

Comment: Noup. By default, the activation function inside the cell is `tanh`. In other words, if you don't provide any activation function when defining the cell it will use `tanh` by default. On the other hand, without activation function (or linear activation function), the learning capability of the cell will be reduced to linear functions due to the lack of non-linearity in the cell.